# HyperV 2008 R2 shows less hdd space for Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

We are trying to install Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS on HyperV 2008 server as virtual machine. We have set 300GB as fixed hdd but while installation of OS the partition manager shows 136gb.

Can you please tell me the fix or solution to install it.

Regards
Caterpillar.

Comment: It seems to have kernel 2.6.32/33. There is a bug in Linux kernel that doesn't detect the virtual IDE adapter correctly and therefore the original 127GB IDE limit is enforced. This sounds like the case here.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I got to know. but we tried it on 2012 hyperv server disk shows properly but network driver having issues, Any idea or document to fix it please.

Comment: Did you add the legacy network adapter or the regular? Legacy works without hv modules as DEC 21140 Tulip

Comment: Yes, we have added HyperV legacy network adapter are added.